# How to open a new empty tab, either " " or about:blank, in a file format other than text/html

Tags: javascript, html, browser, tabs

If I open a new tab using JavaScript and write into it, it is read as `text/html`. HTML tags will work properly inside it. But what if I wanted to open it as a `text/plain`, or maybe `application/xhtml+xml`? `data:,` URLs are not allowed to be opened by all major browsers for security reasons, so I cannot use that method. Putting an `<iframe>` within the tab does work, but that's not what I'm aiming to do.

Edit: Added example code:

```js
const Input = document.querySelector(`textarea`),
VW = screen.width * devicePixelRatio,
VH = screen.height * devicePixelRatio,
NewTab = open(``,`_blank`,`left=${VW/2},top=${VH/2},width=${VW/4},height=${VH/4}`),

UpdatePage = () => 
{
    NewTab.document.documentElement.innerHTML = Input.value;
};

Input.addEventListener
(
    `input`, ()=>
    {
        UpdatePage();
    }
);
```

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

textarea
{
    flex: 1;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea wrap="soft" placeholder="Type stuff to be put into the new tab"></textarea>

<form action="https://cdpn.io/pen/define" method="POST" target="_blank">
 <input type="hidden" name="data" value='{"title": "Example", "html": "<textarea wrap="soft" placeholder="Type stuff to be put into the new tab"></textarea>", "css": "*\n{\n    margin: 0;\n    padding: 0;\n    border: 0;\n}\n\nbody\n{\n  display: flex;\n  flex-direction: column;\n  height: 100vh;\n}\n\ntextarea\n{\n    flex: 1;\n    resize: none;\n}", "js": "const Input = document.querySelector(`textarea`),\nVW = screen.width * devicePixelRatio,\nVH = screen.height * devicePixelRatio,\nNewTab = open(``,`_blank`,`left=${VW/2},top=${VH/2},width=${VW/4},height=${VH/4}`),\n\nUpdatePage = () => \n{\n    NewTab.document.documentElement.innerHTML = Input.value;\n};\n\nInput.addEventListener\n(\n    `input`, ()=>\n    {\n        UpdatePage();\n    }\n);"}'>

 <input type="submit" value="Create New Pen with Prefilled Data">
</form>
```

Comment: maybe add your code, so we can actually see what you are trying to do? opening a .txt file with window.open('test.txt') is no problem at all.

Comment: @rx2347 Updated as requested.

Comment: my comment from earlier is actually wrong, even a .txt is parsed into a dom before being displayed in the browser. this all [goes way way back](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73409) and I don't think it can be done by [document.open](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dynamic-markup-insertion.html) or [window.open](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#dom-open) - not for txt anways, xml seems to be implemented by parser somehow. the real question is: why do this in the first place? layout? to save it? still unclear.

Comment: btw: the easiest way to achieve this might be to simply post all the data to a php script which sets the right headers and outputs this in a new window. done.

Comment: All I need is a reference to the new tab, so that I can modify it's DOM from my html page's JavaScript. I asked this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408298/javascript-getting-a-reference-to-a-new-tab-opened-from-an-a-tag